# How to use the accounts settings via API

Tags: docusignapi

I have created an account and added some features for sending emails, like branding and reminders and expirations.

Now I want to use these features via the API hat will integrate with a specific application for sending automated emails requesting the e-signature.

In the API anyway I will have to specific the text of the email. So the text of the email from the API but the other feature the API should retrieve the ones from the Docusign Account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you can do from the web app - you can do from API too.
One trick I suggest is [recording API logs](https://youtu.be/YJYTDcc7cZw) and then you can see what APIs were called by the web app and do the same yourself.

1. Log in to the DocuSign account of the user for whom you want to
   capture logs.
2. Select the users icon in the top right of the page and
   select My Preferences.
3. Select Enable Logging and then select Save.
4. Reproduce the error while logs are running.
5. Refresh the page on
   which you enabled the logs and select Download, which will download
   the logs to a folder on your computer. See API Request Logging on
   DocuSign Support for a step-by-step example with visuals.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-use-api-logs

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, I will try what you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you want the envelope to use the source account's email reminders and expiration settings, simply specify

```
"notification": {
                     "useAccountDefaults": "true"
                 }
```

For branding, if you don't specify a `brandId`, the account default brand will be used.